# How to install Ubuntu on a computer with a Nvidia Geforce GTX 550 TI?

Tags: installation, nvidia

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bits on my desktop computer, I don't get any video output from the installation since I click "Install Ubuntu" (or something like that). It stays with a black screen just like in a console.

I googled about my problem and I found that maybe Ubuntu isn't capable of showing image when running on a Nvidia Geforce GTX 550 TI, but I couldn't find any solution. How can I install Ubuntu on my dear computer? :P

PS: The problem isn't with the USB I use, I installed already Ubuntu 12.04 64 into my netbook Asus 1215P, and is working fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. When the installation pops up, I clicked F6, then ESC. In the text that appeared on the screen, I changed **quiet** to **noquiet**, **splash** to **nosplash**, and added **nomodeset** right after **nosplash**.

The install finally opened. When installed I checked "install updates during install" and "install third party software" (or something like that) after connected to my wireless network, and when the setup finished and I rebooted my computer, everything was working just fine, with NVidia drivers installed and Unity 3D working.

**For Alternate install:**
After base packages are installed (before grub install), open a prompt (ALT+F2) and "chroot /target", then "apt-get install nvidia-current", "CTRL+D" to exit chroot, "ALT+F1" to resume install. Complete the installation and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

> I figured it out. When the installation pops up, I clicked F6, then ESC. In the text that appeared on the screen, I changed quiet to noquiet, splash to nosplash, and added nomodeset right after nosplash.

This was very helpful and worked for me too

> The install finally opened. When installed I checked "install updates during install" and "install third party software" (or something like that) after connected to my wireless network, and when the setup finished and I rebooted my computer, everything was working just fine, with NVidia drivers installed and Unity 3D working.

I didn't see those options, so after it installed it went back to the test drive.

> For Alternate install: After base packages are installed (before grub install), open a prompt (ALT+F2) and "chroot /target", then "apt-get install nvidia-current", "CTRL+D" to exit chroot, "ALT+F1" to resume install. Complete the installation and you should be good to go.

Don't know, mine installed then I was back at the test drive and couldn't make permanent changes.  Rebooting went to blank screen.

So at that point I rebooted and selected recovery mode and then chose fail safe graphics option.  This allowed me to boot.  Then I was able to go to Ubuntu Software Center and get nvidia current (wow, a lot of bad reviews).  I also was able to run the updates (387 of them).  I was able to reboot to 12.04 ok.  Then I opened system settings, additional drivers, and searched.  Current NVIDIA accelerated driver was activated.  I activated post-release updates.  Rebooted and all is good so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same card and am installing 12.04.  What I usually do is:

1) install the base operating system without X, Unity, etc.
2) boot system and install both nvidia-current-updates, xorg, gnome-shell, lightdm
3) run nvidia-xconfig
4) reboot
5) pray

It typically works, but YMMV.

Comment: Oh, and to install the system initially I use the intel graphics card on my sandy bridge chip.  then switch to the nvidia card in BIOS once I'm on step 4

Comment: I cannot... No onboard graphics driver :(

Comment: Five point is for each point. Pray always. I had a hard fail of GTX460 on 11.10 (just fail to no-signal state) and decided yet to use my old GeForce6600 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have a system with i5 2500k and 550 ti graphics adapter .The first time i tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 desktop i couldn't get any display(Just a Black screen). But later i tried changing Graphics adapter in BIOS to in-Built graphics adapter and then Voilà ! it works
So then installed Ubuntu -->Install NVIDIA X.ORG Current Drivers -->change graphics adapter to 550ti-->
Everything working now
I guess this helps

Answer (score -1):

Do seen some glitches or other visual anomalies??

I have a GTX 560 TI and occasionally colored boxes appear on the screen, even to blocked the desktop Unity and i can't work more with them (reboot to resume).

I install the lasted nVidia Drivers and blocked free nVidia nouveau drivers in blacklist.conf.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the steps to your answer about how you solved the issue?