# nvidia graphics scrambled ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics

I am using a Nvidia GeForce 550Ti graphics card, with a 55" Samsung TV

Everytime I install the Nvidia drivers (either via the gui manager or "apt-get install nvidia-current" The graphic signal gets scrambled upon next reboot, Flashing colors, I tried running nvidia-xconfig it doesn't do anything, I tried nomodeset also.

Here is the weird part, if I switch between the cli  terminal (tty) then switch back, the signal is ok?

Anyone help me out?
I am running ubuntu 12.04 desktop 64 bit

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with an actual camera?

Answer (score 4):

When you boot from the USB or LIVECD - hit <kbd>f6</kbd> and and <kbd>ESC</kbd> which should boot you into text mode. You will need to change the following options in your boot string.

`nosplash, nomodeset`

I found a similar problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127305/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-computer-with-a-nvidia-geforce-gtx-550-ti).

After installation I installed the nvidia driver manually like so:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

reboot and you should have working video.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will give it a go and will let you know

Answer (score 2):

The Nvidia 295.40 grahics driver has a bug and will not work with 12.04 precise. Nvidia are aware of the problem and are working on a fix. You can get around it however by installing the 295.33 driver which will work until Nvidia fixes the current driver. Do the following:

Go to you normal terminal and type in the following:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install nvidia-current=295.33-0ubuntu1~precise~xup1

On reboot it will be working. The update manager will then want to install the current version untick it to stop it from doing so and make sure your updates are only displayed and not installed automatically through settings.

Then if you haven't already done so install Synaptic Package manager and find the 295.33 driver on it you installed. Then go to settings and lock this version. It will get a little lock next to it and turn red. Now the driver cannot be updated until you unlock it. I will be keeping it locked until I am absolutely sure the 295.40 driver has been fixed.