# 12.04 on Intel i7 extreme

Tags: 12.04, intel

Ubuntu 12.04 will not install on MSI Big Bang 2 xPower MoBo with Intel i7 3630 - ? Black screen with blinking cursor and lots of CD and cpu activity, but nothing further happens.
Memory (8 GB) and net ok. Video MSI N560 GTX.

Comment: Did you try booting with option `nomodeset` from grub?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it that way:
Used Alternate CD (text mode installation - for more information pls look ubuntuusers wiki = alternate cd)
=> reboot
=> login and install desktop (f.e.: sudo install ubuntu-desktop)
=> reboot
=> select "save graphic mode" or something similar
=> install proprietary nvidia driver
=> reboot
..with me it worked

Good Luck!
jvbuxtown

Comment: Thanks, worked almost with me. Got scrambled screen at first, but with nomodeset it works. Btw: Found a warning re last update of Nvidia driver, seems to have a bug, se earlier version must be used for 12.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129725/nvidia-graphics-scrambled-ubuntu-12-04 Thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

When the installation pops up, I clicked <kbd>F6</kbd>, then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Scroll down to Install/Run Ubuntu option.

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

In the text that appeared on the screen, I changed splash to :

`nosplash`, and added `nomodeset` right after `nosplash`.

This worked for me... :-)