# Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD won't Boot

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, live-cd, nouveau

I run the installer and when it hits the nouveau video section I see it flash and try to load the desktop, but drops back to a cursor.

It appears that the nouveau drivers are failing with my Geforce GTX 550ti

Does anyone know if there is a work around to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I had the same problem. Found the answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/127305/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-computer-with-a-nvidia-geforce-gtx-550-ti

Answer (score 2):

I had a bunch of problems with installing Ubuntu on this graphics card.

I finally managed to do it, but it took a roundabout solution to finally get it up and running (just managed to do so today). I was unable to get my 11.10 CD or my 12.04.1 CD to boot. What I ended up doing was installing 11.04 and upgrading it to 12.04.1. I ran into a few problems along the way. Since I have a dual boot with Windows 7, when I installed 11.04 it messed up grub. No big deal, I just popped in my 11.04 CD and re-installed grub.

Then I upgraded to 12.04.1. After this install Grub was messed up again, so I popped in my 12.10 CD (which for some reason boots, but the graphics drivers wont work on it) and again reinstalled grub. After I rebooted and chose Ubuntu in grub, I got a purple screen that would flash black. Again, this posed no trouble, I just restarted, entered recovery mode, enabled networking, opened the root prompt and ran `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

Hope this helps you, it took a lot of trial and error to get to this point.

Comment: What is this 10.14 you speak of? Ubuntu is named by YY.MM - and only 04 or 10. 10.14 doesn't make any sense, so changed it to the most likely thing you could mean. If you mean something else, please change it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had the same problem recently, I've browsed every forum and did extensive research on the issue with no solutions, after fooling around, me and a friend figured it out! As soon as you install Linux, go into the bios. Under the bios you will have the option of the hard drive running in achi mode or IDE mode, make sure it's on IDE mode and it should boot fine afterwords.

Comment: Was the problem you used this technique to fix a video problem, like the original poster's problem here in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Nouveau has had serious issues with Nvidia GTX 5X series graphics from the start. There isn't an easy workaround. You basically need a liveUSB or CD with the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed. I managed to create a liveUSB system and boot from a computer with a  Nvidia video card and then installed the Nvidia drivers. After that you can use [Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/) to create a live CD with Nvidia drivers.

If anyone expresses interest in hosting a torrent file, I have the 12.04 amd64 live CD with Nvidia drivers already installed.