# Installation doesn't start

Tags: 12.04, installation

I wanted to try out ubuntu on my desktop PC. I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version and burned it on a CD. When boot the CD and got those option to chose if I want to install ubuntu or run it from the CD. I chose to install ubuntu. When I press enter it's going to load and you'll see a "-" sign in the top left corner of my screen. After that nothing happends.

*edit*
I may not answer my own questions so i'll edit this one but i tried to run the installation with acpi=off and now the installation starts. If its still needed my graphic card is GTX550 ti and my processor is Q8400 @ 2.66 ghz

Comment: What are your system specifications?

Comment: The "-" suggests that the problem is with video. As well as general system specifications can you tell us specifically about your graphic card?

Comment: I have a GTX550 ti graphic card

Comment: Then, please look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127305/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-a-computer-with-a-nvidia-geforce-gtx-550-ti

Answer (score 0):

Check the MD5SUM of your CD? Sometimes when you burn an ISO the data get corrupted. Check this [How To MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Answer (score -1):

You can also try burning cd again and make sure that your internet connection is unplugged while burning the cd.This might help

Comment: Downvote: Why?. I fail to understand how having internet unplugged while burning a CD can help.

Comment: @Javier This worked out for me so i suggested.someone suggested this to me

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep the downvote then. If is no reason for this to work, nor way to reproduce it, I'm quite sure that your experience is just coincidence and that this advice is incorrect.

Comment: To help your computer "focus" disable your Internet connectivity, turn off your firewall, and disable your antivirus, anti-spyware, and other malware-protection software during the burning process.see this site:http://www.wikihow.com/Burn-a-DVD

Comment: Focus?. Sorry, this still doesn't make any sense to me.